# Ping one way or back

Tags: java, bukkit

I have to know the exact ping of a player for a reaction test.
I use Handlers for this:

```
public int pingPlayer(Player p) {
    try {
        String bukkitversion = Bukkit.getServer().getClass().getPackage().getName().substring(23);
        Class<?> craftPlayer = Class.forName("org.bukkit.craftbukkit." + bukkitversion + ".entity.CraftPlayer");
        Object handle = craftPlayer.getMethod("getHandle").invoke(p);
        Integer ping = (Integer) handle.getClass().getDeclaredField("ping").get(handle);
        return ping.intValue();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

But now I dont know if the ping is one way [Server --> Player] or two ways [Server --> Player --> Server]

Does somewone know, how exactly this works?

Comment: Pings are round-trip

Comment: Sure that it is the same in bukkit?

Comment: @NicolaUetz Thats how ping works. It counts the time it took round trip(Somthing like this don't quote me XD). You can also simply use `int ping = ((CraftPlayer)p).getHandle().playerConnection.player.ping;` You have no need for reflection here.

Comment: @Lightspeed360 unless you want to try and provide a version independence :P CraftPlayer is version depended thus you either use abstraction or reflection.

Comment: @fillpant Then you can update your plugin? Yes his system is good, but on a server with only 1 version you can use the very simple line.

Comment: @Lightspeed360 Yeah but i mean, servers will depend on your plugin, and will cause confusion when they see the wonderfull error in console because they updated and stuff and also you are tied to update it every single version that pops out... 
:/
I would prefer reflection with a good system to catch exceptions, or at last a self-compiling code that compiles and executes during runtime and can be edited programmatically. (possible, Dynamic Class Compilation)

Comment: @fillpant I think than the server-owners can use the specialsource to update the plugin?!

Comment: @Nightfighter001 Yes. What im trying to convey is that you as a developer will  have to update the plugin every new version, let alone server owners who have to update it somehow (I remind you to read Bukkit's auto-update policy). So essentially, if 2.0 comes out, you need to update your plugin as soon as possible before server owners who depend on it go balistic.

Comment: @NicolaUetz do you already need a reply yet ?

Comment: @Elikill58 it's a round-trip time. So server-player-server.